# Inserting into a map in a function

Tags: rust

Im still trying to wrap my head around lifetimes in rust but ive run into a problem. I have a struct that has a map and im tryign to add to that map in a function. It maps a string id to an object:

```
pub struct AGVController<'a> {
    agv_map: HashMap<&'a str, AGV>
}

impl AGVController<'_> {
    // Create a new AGV Controller
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            agv_map: HashMap::new()
        }
    }
    // Add a new AGV
    pub fn add_agv(&mut self, ip_addr: &str) -> Option<&str> {
        let new_agv = AGV::new(ip_addr);
        match self.agv_map.get(ip_addr) {
            Some(_) => {
                let result = format!("AGV with ip address {} already exists", ip_addr);
                return Some(result.as_str());
            },
            None => {
                self.agv_map.insert(ip_addr, new_agv);
            }
        }
        return Some("");
    }
}
```

in add new I want to create a new instance and add that to the map. Im getting the following error:

```
lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
  --> src/agv/agv_controller.rs:58:37
   |
58 |                 self.agv_map.insert(ip_addr, new_agv);
   |                                     ^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...the reference is valid for the lifetime `'_` as defined here...
  --> src/agv/agv_controller.rs:16:20
   |
16 | impl AGVController<'_> {
   |                    ^^
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime defined here
  --> src/agv/agv_controller.rs:50:40
   |
50 |     pub fn add_agv(&mut self, ip_addr: &str) -> Option<&str> {
   |                                        ^^^^
```

It seems like it is saying that the reference in the map will outlive the reference of the parameter passed in, which is fair I guess.
Can someone explain to me how I add an entry to a map in a function where the key is passed into the function?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you might also want to look at the [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API instead of `get`+`insert`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails because the lifetime of the `ip_addr` reference is only valid while the `add_agv` method executes, but it needs to be valid for the `'a` in `AGVController<'a>`.  To fix this, add the `'a` lifetime to your `impl` block and use it for this parameter:

```
impl<'a> AGVController<'a> {
    // ...

    pub fn add_agv(&mut self, ip_addr: &'a str) -> Option<&str> {
```

Which brings us to the second problem: you attempt to return a `&str` to a `String` that is owned by this function (in `result`).  This is simply impossible; return an `Option<String>` instead, making the appropriate changes to your `return` statements.

```
pub fn add_agv(&mut self, ip_addr: &'a str) -> Option<String> {
```

```
return Some(result);
```

```
return Some("".to_owned());
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=322684f2ceedd2c9148bbd13c419d772))

---

Alternatively, consider returning a `Result`, which is a better way to indicate an operation that can fail:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter, Error as FmtError};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DuplicateIPAddress(pub String);

impl Error for DuplicateIPAddress {}

impl Display for DuplicateIPAddress {
    fn fmt(&self, w: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), FmtError> {
        write!(w, "Duplicate IP address {}", self.0)
    }
}
```

Now your function can return `Result<(), DuplicateIPAddress>`:

```
pub fn add_agv(&mut self, ip_addr: &'a str) -> Result<(), DuplicateIPAddress> {
```

```
return Err(DuplicateIPAddress(ip_addr.to_owned()));
```

```
return Ok(());
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=69efbd4a4912b898461b893f15aa1e3b))

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I did try and return a Result at first but had no idea about the second part you did there. This is definitely my preferred way of doing it. For the first part. I didnt realise the lifetime of the impl would be different from the lifetime of the object. Its taking a while to get straight on a lot of this stuff

Comment: @discodowney Yep, Rust requires approaching almost completely differently than a lot of other languages, which are all more or less the same concepts behind different syntax.

Comment: Just tested and everything is working. One last question. You made the Error AddAGVError, is the convention to create an error for each scenario or a class Error and then have the enum filled with all the options and the match handle what to do for each?

Comment: @discodowney I'd say it's generally bad form to have a "universal" error type. The error type for a particular function should ideally only cover errors that can actually happen in that function, otherwise if the caller wants to inspect the error they are forced to handle a bunch of cases that will never happen.

Comment: @discodowney Note I've updated my answer; it made little sense for the error type to be an enum since there's only one way this function can fail. I've changed it to simply return a single kind of error.

Comment: Okay. All this is great. Want to get on the road with the best practices from the start so definitely gonna go around and update some stuff I already made. Though i think this might be the only custom error ive made so far...

Comment: @discodowney This is not the only way how errors can be handled. An alternative for _binary_ crates is using [eyre](https://docs.rs/eyre/latest/eyre/) (or [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/)). For _library_ crates, this is often frowned upon, however.